# Show the group isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p_1^{k_1})^\times \times \cdots \times (\mathbb{Z}/p_n^{k_n})^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

When $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime we have the ring isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/rs \cong \mathbb{Z}/r \times \mathbb{Z}/s$

Given a prime factorization of $n$ where $n = p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_n^{k_n}$

Show that for groups of units invertible under multiplication:

$(\mathbb{Z}/n)^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p_1^{k_1})^\times \times \cdots \times (\mathbb{Z}/p_n^{k_n})^\times$

Comment: Hint: Since you know $\mathbb{Z}/rs\simeq\mathbb{Z}/r\times\mathbb{Z}/s$ as *rings*, then you know that the units of one map to units to the other.  This shows $\mathbb{Z}/rs^\times\simeq\mathbb{Z}/r^\times\times\mathbb{Z}/s^\times$ (there is something small to be checked here, namely that the units of $(\mathbb{Z}/r\times\mathbb{Z}/s)$ are $\mathbb{Z}/r^\times\mathbb{Z}/s^\times$).  Then, use induction.

Comment: Thank you! Can you get me started on the induction proof of that last point. Thanks!

Comment: Induct on the number of distinct prime factors.  The case where there is one distinct prime factor is easy ...

Comment: In the inductive step I need to show $\left(\mathbb{Z}/r \times \mathbb{Z}/s\right)^\times = \left(\mathbb{Z}/r\right)^\times \times \left(\mathbb{Z}/s\right)^\times$ for relatively prime $r$ and $s$. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base case: You've already done it.

$\mathbb{Z}/n^{\times} = \left(\mathbb{Z}/\prod_{i=1}^{j} p_i ^{k_j}\right)^{\times}= \bigg(\mathbb{Z}/\left(\prod_{i=1}^{j-1} p_i^{k_i}\right)\cdot p_j^{k_j}\bigg)^{\times} \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^j \left(\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{k_i}\right)^{\times}$

The product of the $p_i^{k_i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq j-1$ is relatively prime with $p_j^{k_j}$.

The induction hypothesis would be to suppose it is true up to $j-1$, then we show above that up to $j$ resolves to the base case.